# overflow:hidden ignored with border-radius and CSS transforms (webkit only)

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to have a square image inside a circle.

When the user hovers over the image, the image should scale (zoom in).

The circle should remain the same size.

Only during the CSS transition, the square image overlaps the circle (as if overflow:hidden weren't there at all).

Here's a demo with the weird behavior in Chrome and Safari:
http://codepen.io/jshawl/full/flbau

Working ok in firefox.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I removed some superfluous markup (the circle and square containers... only needs one) and styled the img itself:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);
}

#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

#test:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEzLzA1LzA4L2JlL2JhYmllc193aXRoLjA5NGNjLnBuZwpwCXRodW1iCTg1MHg1OTA-CmUJanBn/8f195417/e44/babies_with_swagg.jpg" id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: the circle should stay the same size

Comment: dont over complecate it this is the answer position:relative;
z-index:1;

Answer (score 50):

You need to add this code to the parent of your img :

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

Example here : http://codepen.io/DavidN/pen/dIzJK

Comment: I already had `position:relative`, but adding `z-index:1` fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks David, this was bugging me for ages.

Comment: Yes this solution worked a treat for me. I wasn't using a circle, so didn't want to use the mask. Seems kind of obvious now.

Comment: Another +1 here, this works when you have an image inside an anchor with rounded corners and want to 'zoom in' on hover. Simple when you think about it. Thanks

Comment: This is better answer as using mask also hides box-shadow.

Comment: This has helped me, thanks! Lesson learned - always apply some kind of positioning to the block element. Block in BEM methodology.

Comment: It seems that fix doesn't work anymore (17th of May, 2017; Chrome 58).

Comment: It is working for me here : http://codepen.io/DavidN/pen/dIzJK with Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

Add this code to your parent div and solve problem :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though you were styling one too many elements! I've created a [fork here](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/mKHFr)

I edited some of your SASS code to utilize the compass library and make better use of the `transition` and `transform` properties which can be seen here:

```
body { padding: 3em; }

.circle {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    @include border-radius(500px);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    @include transition(all 0.3s ease);
    &:hover { @include transform(scale(1.1)); }
}
```

Hopefully this helps! Just think of the `circle` element as the parent container which has general information about the space (e.g. `500px` wide and `500px` tall). The image itself has a rounded border of `500px`. This is the element you want to edit! You can scale and transform this element here without interacting with the parent `circle` container. Reference [compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) for additional information about using the library! Good luck!

Comment: It's weird that adding overflow:hidden to the image works. Shouldn't it be on the parent?

Comment: The best way to find out is by trying! Remove the `overflow` property from `.circle img` and place it in `.circle` and see the results. Do you even need the `overflow` property?

Comment: oh wait I just realized your fork makes the circle bigger. the circle should stay the same size. the image should get bigger

Comment: see this fork. no border radius works. border radius doesn't http://codepen.io/jshawl/pen/skGJl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31054/discussion-between-djthoms-and-jessh)