# Cross browser css transistion

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with given below code

### This is my stylesheet

```
.h_w:hover img{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); 
         -moz-transform: scale(1.1); 
          -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
           -o-transform: scale(1.1);
              transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transition: 5s all;
       -moz-transition: 5s all;
         -o-transition: 5s all;
        -ms-transition: 5s all;
            transition: 5s all;
}
.h_w{ border-radius:200px;
       -moz-border-radius: 200px;
        -ms-border-radius: 200px;
         -o-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    height: 287px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 287px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}    
.opacity-0.5{opacity:0.2;}
.circle_background{ 
    background:url(../images/circle-bg.png) no-repeat; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:15px;
    opacity:1 !important;
    top: 286px;
}    
.h_w:hover .circle_background{
            transition:1s all;
       -moz-transition:1s all;
        -ms-transition:1s all;
         -o-transition:1s all;
    -webkit-transition:1s all;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1000px;
}
```

### And this is my HTML

```
<body style="background-color: #000000;">
    <div class="h_w">
        <span><img src="images/projects/circles/background.png" alt="flick the switch" /></span>
    </div>                
</body>
```

This code is working fine in Mozilla firefox but in chrome it is not working when zooming it is going outside the circle.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind making a fiddle?

Comment: Ya, would be great to get used pictures to see the excpected effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here for your answer: [--->X<---](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878279/overflowhidden-ignored-with-border-radius-and-css-transforms-webkit-only)

PS: you must add `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);` to your img's parent-div styles.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will work .

```
  .h_w:hover  img{
         -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
             -moz-transform: scale(1.1); 
              -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
               -o-transform: scale(1.1);
                  transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transition: 5s img ;
           -moz-transition: 5s img ;
             -o-transition: 5s img ;
            -ms-transition: 5s img ;
                transition: 5s img ;
    }
```

here above you can see that .h_w:hover img rule uses transtion property.
In transtion property  I use img because You would like to create a motion on "img" not "all" property
So use "img" instead of "all".
Hope the answer!

Comment: Just click that this answer is useful!