# How to retain image round corners during transition of image hover zoom in?

Tags: css

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jcbuwf9r/3/)

Image zoom in on hover is easy.
Image round borders is easy.
Combining them, OK, but round corners disappear during transition.
After transition, round corners are back.
**Question:** How to retain round corners during transition?

```
.img-wrapper {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    transform:scale(1);
}

.img-wrapper img:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try add this:

```
.img-wrapper {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

if still not worknig, try something from this question:
[overflow:hidden ignored with border-radius and CSS transforms (webkit only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878279/overflowhidden-ignored-with-border-radius-and-css-transforms-webkit-only)

Answer (score 2):

add `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);` to the class `img-wrapper` and added some style  here is the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/bfugwwq0/)

Comment: @KaFaiLo plz check this and tell me !!

Comment: This is the first time I see `mask-image`.  The answer of Pepo_rasta is tested ok, and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Move your border-radius from your wrapper to your image.

```
.img-wrapper {
    width: 400px;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    transform:scale(1);
}

.img-wrapper img:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Blue border gone when zoom in.

Comment: fiddle: no, the requirement is to see the same visible image dimensions while the image zooms in -- seeing less of the sides of the image.  Your fiddle shows the entire image while zooming in, so the visible dimensions change.